# How to add new dates rows to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a massive data frame where the data goes until 2022.06.30 and I want to add new rows to it until 2022.06.30. How can it be done?

Comment: Please show what you've tried and where you get stuck. This seems like a simple case for `seq`. Do you have your variable in `Date` format?

Comment: I've tried the add_row function :  df %>% add_row(date = 2739:2923). I just need to add more dates to an existing column, which is already in a date format. I understood that in the argument must contain the interval of the desired new rows

Comment: I.e. `data <- as.Date("2022.06.30","%Y.%m.%d")` . Then `data +1:100` gives you 1 to 100 days later.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this is usually to define a new date array, by using:

```
new_dates <- seq_Date(from = data$date[1], to = target_date, by = "day")
```

Now define a tibble with the other columns initialized as NA. The number of rows in this tibble will be the length of the date sequence.

```
new_df <- dplyr::tibble(date = new_dates, column1 = NA, column2 = NA, ...)
```

For the last step, assuming you named the columns correctly, just do:

```
new_df[seq_len(nrow(old_df)), c(-date)] <- old_df
```

Which means that you will be updating all the rows from 1 to the number of rows you had in the old dataframe and all the columns, except the date column, which you had just defined.